# Right way to parse Redux state props - using super json objects

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

Following my trip with React and Redux, I'm facing a problem, simple in appearance, but hard to solve : I'm setting my Redux state with a very big JSON object. Those datas are retrieved from an async call. When I'm setting it, I created an entry in my reducer with

```
let initialState = {
  pages: []
}
```

Then, I'm putting different pages, with their params and datas into this `pages`array. So far so good, the state is well updated.

BUT, my different app pages use only parts of it as you can imagine. For instance, I have a page named `Gallery` which might need my state to look like this :

```
"pages": [
  {
    "component":"Gallery",
    "key": "gallery",
    "title": "Galerie photos",
    "url": "/galerie-photos",
    "sections": [
      {
        "component": "Gallery",
        "params": {
          "images": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "src": "http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/627/300/1",
              "alt": "alternate text"
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "src": "http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/500/400/2",
              "alt": "alternate text"
            },
            {
              "id": 3,
              "src": "http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/400/320/3",
              "alt": "alternate text"
            },
            {
              "id": 4,
              "src": "http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/800/500/4",
              "alt": "alternate text"
            },
            {
              "id": 5,
              "src": "http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/320/300/5",
              "alt": "alternate text"
            },
            {
              "id": 6,
              "src": "http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/420/360/6",
              "alt": "alternate text"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

In my `GalleryContainer`, I'm requesting only the `images` property as this is the only concern of my `Gallery` component. I'm able to retrieve this data with no problem. Testing with the following code returns the desired images array :

But as far as I tested this, the images are not retrieved by my `Gallery`component : when console logging on the component side, I got `undefined`, and on the container side, no problem.

I tested something different : I set a `galleryImages` property via the reducer, and set it with the gallery images directly. This worked.

The questions are : Why doesn't it work in the first case, and do in the second ? Do I have to work only with datas that are set as state properties only ? Can't I have a "super" json set in my state to work with directly ?

Thanks to light me up on this one :)

```js
// Component
import React from 'react'

const Gallery = ({images}) => (
  <div>
    {images.map((image, key) =>
      <div key={key} className="image-element-class" style={card}>
        <img src={image.src} alt={image.alt} style={imageStyle}/>
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
)

const card = {
  width: 'calc((100% / 3) - (15px / 1.5))',
  marginBottom: '15px',
  boxSizing: 'border-box'
}

const imageStyle = {
  width: '100%'
}

export default Gallery

// Container
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Gallery from '../../components/pages/Gallery'

const getImages = state => {

  return {
    images: state.data.pages.filter(page => page.component === 'Gallery' &&(
      page.sections.filter(section => section.component === 'Gallery' &&(
        section.params.images
      ))
    )),
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return getImages(state)
}

const GalleryContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {}
)(Gallery)

export default GalleryContainer
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: please attach your container and component source to the question

Comment: I updated the post with the full snippets

Comment: well, you'd have to append `[0].sections[0].params.images` to your `getImages`' return statement in order to get the images array, though this might not be a good idea without testing for actual length or existing properties..

Comment: I ended removing Redux and just pass the initial properties values down to the children components. 
But just to clarify : The main issue was about parsing maps instead of arrays in es6. This was kinda tricky.